# Why does my compiler insist that operator<< has 3 parameters when it has 2?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++17, friend

This seems so simple, and I've overloaded operators before, but now i get the error message 
`error: overloaded 'operator<<' must be a binary operator (has 3 parameters)`. I feel like there is something obvious I'm missing, but after googling for some hours I just can't seem to figure it out ... In my .h file i have this

```
class NeuralNet{
    private:
        vector<Layer*> layers;
    public:
        NeuralNet(){}
        void addLayer(Layer*);
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const NeuralNet);
};
```

and in my .cpp file I have this

```
ostream& NeuralNet::operator<<(ostream& os, NeuralNet& net){
    for (Layer* l : net.layers){
        os << l->getSize() << " ";
    }
    os << "\n";
    for (Layer* l : net.layers){
        os << l->getInputSize() << " ";
    }
    os << endl; 
    return os;
}
```

`Layer`is currently a dummy-class, getInputSize() and getSize() just return `int`s, there are no self-defined namespaces involved. I want to keep the `vector<Layer*> layers` private, and I have written code earlier using `friend` so that `operator<<` can be allowed to access private variables. However now, if i don't declare `operator<<` as `friend` and remove the `NeuralNet::` in the .cpp file I (obviously) get the error `error: 'layers' is a private member of 'NeuralNet'`, but when I include it i get said error message.

Comment: This might not be a satisfactory explanation but you have `const NeuralNet` in your declaration's signature and `NeuralNet&` in your definition. Both should be `const NeuralNet&`. Does that change the error message?

Comment: Friend functions aren't members of a class. Remove the `NeuralNet::` from your definition.

Comment: `NeuralNet::operator<<(...)` is the definition of a member function. Has an implicit `this` argument like all non-static member functions.

Comment: @Vegard Jervell It is just a silly compiler. It shall say that such a member function does not exist.:)

Comment: Thanks all! I believe it was a combination of the above that made me introduce new errors when fixing other ones :P Silly mistakes that, show up around 23:30... thanks again for friendly help :)

Answer (score 2):

```
ostream& NeuralNet::operator<<(ostream& os, NeuralNet& net){ ... }
```

needs to be

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, NeuralNet& net){
```

since you have declared it to be `friend` function, not a member function.